# Two routers connected to each other - PCs can't see each other when connected to different routers

Tags: networking, router

It's the same access point (wireless) and same ISP connection. However, if I'm connected to router #1, I can't see any content on Router #2 on the local network. Is there a way to fix this? It cripples my ability to stream. :)

Comment: Use the second router as (or replace it with) a switch or access point, leave its WAN side unused.

Comment: Can you explain your setup? You have one access point and two routers? What are those routers doing? And are the routers bridging? If so, how? WDS? Which device is the DHCP server or do you have more than one DHCP server? Which device is doing NAT or are more than one?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I've got a Rogers Modem (Hitron) / Router hybrid and what appears to be this router. http://www.bestbuy.com/site/NETGEAR---150-Wireless-N-Router-with-4-Port-Ethernet-Switch/9612883.p?id=1218131364790&skuId=9612883#tab=specifications

Someone else configured it - so I'm not sure how it's setup currently. I can't access the Netgear as the PCs I've tried all seem to access the rogers modem via the gateway URL.

Comment: I'll also note we have one access point - wireless devices are fine it's jsut some of the ethernet devices are plugged into the netgear. Those can't see the ones on the rogers modem.

Comment: @VaughanHilts: It sounds like someone set you up with multiple LANs for some reason.

Comment: Is there a way I can reconfigure this easily?'

Comment: @VaughanHilts: Maybe, but we need much more detail about your current setup. Are the two routers connected together by wires? If so, is the connection to the second router's (the one not connected to the Internet) LAN port or WAN port?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming your second router (the one that doesn't connect to the Internet) is wired to the other router by a LAN-to-WAN connection. This is the problem -- you should not connect a LAN port to a WAN port (other than connecting a router to a modem) unless you have a very unusual reason to do so.

Here's the fix:

1. Log into the second router and disable its DHCP server.
2. Move the connection to the first router from the second router's WAN port to one of its LAN ports.
3. Do not use the second router's WAN port, the second router is not connected to a WAN.
4. Make sure the second router's LAN port IP address assignment does not conflict with the first router's LAN IP assignment. The best IP to assign is one inside the first router's subnet but outside its DHCP range. (Or you can just hope this won't be a problem. Or change it to something unlikely to conflict like 192.168.205.1)
5. If you know how to do a DHCP release/renew on each computer connected to the second router, do so. Otherwise, reboot each machine connected to the second router.

Comment: Worked a treat, thanks for saving me some money on a switch. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can just pick one router as primary (the more powerful one), and setup the other one in *bridge* mode. Every device attached to both routers will be in the same local network.

Comment: How would I do this? When I go to my Gateway URL, all I see is my Rogers box web UI.

Comment: Each router will have its own configuration URL. You should look at the manual of them.

Comment: I'm using this, but my devices under switch (connected to router) dont see each other, just other devices connected to router.

Answer (score 0):

This means that the two routers are not exchanging the routing tables. If you are using DD-WRT, set the router connected to the internet as Gateway in the Operation Mode setting. And set the other router to Router. Make sure a dynamic routing protocol (like RIP2) is used between the two routers so they can exchange the routing table.

And double check the security, firewall, and discoverability settings if they are not in line with what you want.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Before answering an old question having an accepted answer (look for green ✓) as well as other answers ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [answer]. There is also a site [tour] and  a [help].